# Combobox that will depend its values from another combobox

Tags: mysql, vb.net, combobox

I have 2 comboboxes. combobox1 have values NHM,Science and Technology,SAM and combobox2 is null until you select a value on combobox1. If i select NHM combobox2 should have values HRM,Tourism and if i select SAM the values of combobox2 should show me Accountancy,Management. I am trying to do it all day i can't figure out the correct syntax. I am using unbound mode on my combobox1. Unfortunately i can only save my combobox1 on my database. Hence i have no idea what syntax to use because im new at using VB.

Comment: That code is totally unrelated to the question (and has various issues).  Are you saying the 2 cbos act like a header-detail situation where the *contents* of #2 depends on the selection in #1?

Comment: @Plutonix Yes! contents of #2 will depend on #1. What various issue?

Comment: Dont concat SQL for one thing; you should [Edit] your post with code related to the cbo issue(s)

Comment: @Plutonix I see... I dont have an idea on how to start with the cbo issue cant find a tutorial regards to my problem.. Should i use case? if and else?  Thanks

Comment: Well there is little we can do to help given what is there:  we have no idea of the data store at all.  It sounds like the first CBO could be bound to a datasource and simple respond to changes there

Comment: @Plutonix uhmmm. When to use Data Bound and Unbound mode on cbo? The value of cbo1 and cbo2 will be stored in their assigned column. The value of cbo2 will just depend on cbo1 because there are many choices to choose from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you just do something like the below for each case? Unbound is fine.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As   System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString = "NHM" Then
        ComboBox2.Items.Add("HRM")
        ComboBox2.Items.Add("Tourism")
        ComboBox2.Refresh()

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Also if you want to have combo Box 2 be automatically selected with something base on one you could, instead of refresh use ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = ComboBox2.FindStringExact("HRM")

Comment: That way works, but you will want to add to clear the options from combobox 2 first, so that the only options are what pertain to the selection in combobox 1.

Comment: @codeMonger123 It Works! But how to remove the values HRM and tourism from cb2 if i choose other value from cb1?

Comment: you could place this  ComboBox2.Items.Clear() before you IF conditions in order to clear all values out of combobox2. Every time the value changes it will clear then add to combobox2.